# Unique random number for a particular timestamp

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures

I am kind of learning concepts of Random number generation & Multithreading in java.

The idea is to not generating a repeated random number of range 1000 in a particular millisecond (Considering, not more than 50 data, in a multithreaded way will be processed in a millisecond). So that list of generated random number at the specific time is unique. Can you give me any idea as i am ending up generating couple of repeated random numbers (also, there is a considerable probability) in a particular milli second.

I have tried the following things where i failed.

```
Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());
double randomNum = random.nextInt(999);
```

//

```
int min=1; int max=999;
double randomId = (int)Math.abs(math.Random()* (max - min + 1) + min);
```

//

```
Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime()); // also tried new Random();
double randomId = (int)Math.abs(random.nextDouble()* (max - min + 1) + min);
```

As I am appending the timestamp that is being generated, in a multithreaded environment i see the same ids (around 8-10) that is being generated (2-4 times) for 5000+ unique data.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some of your code. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: It would be better you'd try to clarify one thing after the other. For example, multithreading has nothing to do with generating random numbers, so we should not confuse it.

Comment: What are max and min?

Comment: gud catch ingo, i actually started to type some other question!! ended up asking this question!!

Comment: min max are the range 1-999!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class will allow you to get nonrepeating values from a certain range until the whole range has been used. Once the range is used, it will be reinitialized.

Class comes along with a simple test.

If you want to make the class thread safe, just add `synchronized` to `nextInt()` declaration.

Then you can use the singleton pattern or just a static variable to access the generator from multiple threads. That way all your threads will use the same object and the same unique id pool.

```
public class NotRepeatingRandom {
    int size;
    int index;
    List<Integer> vals;
    Random gen = new Random();

    public NotRepeatingRandom(int rangeMax) {
      size = rangeMax;
      index = rangeMax; // to force initial shuffle
      vals = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
      fillBaseList();
    }

    private void fillBaseList() {
      for (int a=0; a<size; a++) {
        vals.add(a);
      }
    }

    public int nextInt() {
      if (index == vals.size()) {
          Collections.shuffle(vals);
          index = 0;
      }
      int val = vals.get(index);
      index++;      
      return val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NotRepeatingRandom gen = new NotRepeatingRandom(10);
        for (int a=0; a<30; a++) {
            System.out.println(gen.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouch - for a naïve implementation, I like where this is going, but will have some terrible performance problems.  Constantly removing a random element like that will cause the entire array to be shifted (one...element...at...a...time...).  Better to shuffle `curVals` in `rebuildCurVals()`, and then constantly remove the _last_ element in the list.  Or, maybe look into using a different (perhaps custom `Queue` implementation?) data structure.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse you are right, though I feel very strongly about following the first law of optimization, which is "do not optimize". The class is well encapsulated, and can be easily replaced with a more optimal implementation if such need arises.

Comment: Instead of two lists, just store an int pointing to the next index from baseVals. Increase it by one whenever `nextInt()` is called and when index > baseVals.size(): shuffle baseVals, then reset the index to zero.

Comment: @Pyranja here you go. I still think that the optimization is a different issue.

Answer (score 4):

First, you should use `new Random()`, since it looks [like this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Random.java) (details depend on Java version):

```
 public Random() { this(++seedUniquifier + System.nanoTime()); }
 private static volatile long seedUniquifier = 8682522807148012L;
```

I.e. it already makes use of `nanoTime()` *and* makes sure different threads with the same `nanoTime()` result get different seeds, which `new Random(System.nanoTime())` doesn't.

(EDIT: Pyranja pointed out this is a bug in Java 6, but it's fixed [in Java 7](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Random.java?av=f):

```
public Random() {
    this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());
}

private static long seedUniquifier() {
    // L'Ecuyer, "Tables of Linear Congruential Generators of
    // Different Sizes and Good Lattice Structure", 1999
    for (;;) {
        long current = seedUniquifier.get();
        long next = current * 181783497276652981L;
        if (seedUniquifier.compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
}

private static final AtomicLong seedUniquifier
    = new AtomicLong(8682522807148012L);
```

)

Second, if you generate 50 random numbers from 1 to 1000, the probability some numbers will be the same is quite high thanks to [the birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Third, if you just want unique ids, you could just use `AtomicInteger` counter instead of random numbers. Or if you want a random part to start with, append a counter as well to guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: Imho the shown mechanism is not thread-safe. It is possible, that two different threads use the same `seedUniquifier`. Although `seedUniquifier` is volatile, the `++` operator is *not* atomic. To be on the safe side, one should use an AtomicInteger or AtomicLong to hold the seed value or other means of proper synchronization.

Comment: @Pyranja Good point. That's probably why it was fixed in Java 7, which does use AtomicLong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, multiple threads are creating their own instances of Random class at the same time and all threads generate the same random number?
Same number is generated, because all random instances where created at the same time, i.e. with the same seed.

To fix this, create only one instance of Random class, which is shared by all threads so that all your threads call nextDouble() on the same instance. Random.nextDouble() class is thread safe and will implicitly update its seed with every call.

```
//create only one Random instance, seed is based on current time
public static final Random generator= new Random();
```

Now all threads should use the same instance:

```
double random=generator.nextDouble()
```